# TypeError: Member "isUserBlackListed" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract IERC20

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I created the ERC20 smartcontract and presale token contract. But when I try to call the function token.isUserBlacklisted(msg.sender) from the ERC20 contract I receive the next error: TypeError: Member "isUserBlackListed" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in contract IERC20. The same situation happens when I try to call function mint, addToBlacklist, removeFromBlacklist. What am I doing wrong?

The code of ERC20 contract is:

````
pragma solidity 0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/extensions/ERC20Burnable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract SolarGreen is ERC20, ERC20Burnable, Ownable {
    mapping (address => bool) private isBlacklisted;
    event AddressBlacklisted(address indexed addr, bool isBlacklisted);

    constructor(address shop)
        ERC20("SolarGreen", "SGR")
        Ownable(shop)
    {
        _mint(msg.sender, 100000000 * 10 ** decimals());
    }

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        require(amount > 0, "amount must be positive");
        _mint(to, amount);
    }

    function addToBlacklist(address user) public onlyOwner {
        require(isBlacklisted[user] != true, "user is already in blacklist");
        require(user != address(0), "can't BL 0 address");
        isBlacklisted[user] = true;
        emit AddressBlacklisted(user, true);
    }
    
    function removeFromBlacklist(address user) public onlyOwner {
        require(isBlacklisted[user] != false, "user is already removed from blacklist");
        require(user != address(0), "can't remove from BL 0 address");
        isBlacklisted[user] = false;
        emit AddressBlacklisted(user, false);
    }

    function isUserBlacklisted(address user) public view returns (bool) {
        return isBlacklisted[user];
    }
}```


The code of sale token contract is:


```// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

pragma solidity 0.8.20;

import "./SolarGreen.sol";

contract TokenSale{
    IERC20 public token;
    address payable public owner;
    uint256 public saleStart;
    uint256 public saleEnd;
    uint256 public tokensBalanceForSale;
    bool public isUserBlacklisted;
    
    mapping (address => uint256) public userTokenBalances;

    event Bought(uint _amount, address indexed _buyer);

    constructor() {
        token = new SolarGreen(address(this));
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
        saleStart = block.timestamp;
        saleEnd = saleStart + 5 weeks;
        tokensBalanceForSale = token.balanceOf(address(this)) / 2;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "not an owner");
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyActive {
        require(block.timestamp >= saleStart, "sale must be active.");
        require(block.timestamp <= saleEnd, "sale must be active.");
        _;
    }

   function getUserTokenBalance(address user) public view returns (uint256){
        return userTokenBalances[user];
   }

   function changeSaleEnd (uint _newSaleEnd) public onlyOwner {
        saleEnd = _newSaleEnd;
   }

    receive() external payable onlyActive {
        uint256 tokensForSale = msg.value / 100; // 1 token = 100 wei
        require(token.isUserBlacklisted(msg.sender) = false, "user is blacklisted");
        require(msg.sender != address(0), "zero address");
        require(msg.sender.balance >= msg.value, "not enough funds");
        require(tokensForSale > 0, "impossible to buy 0 tokens");
        require((getUserTokenBalance(msg.sender) + tokensForSale) <= 50000, "token sale limit" ); //checking the purchase limit of 50,000 tokens per one wallet
        require(tokensForSale <= tokensBalanceForSale, "not enough tokens");

        userTokenBalances[msg.sender] += tokensForSale;
        
        token.transfer(msg.sender, tokensForSale);
        tokensBalanceForSale -= tokensForSale;
        emit Bought(tokensForSale, msg.sender);
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to call `isUserBlackListed` with an uppercase **L** in the function name, which should be `isUserBlacklisted`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're attempting to use the standard `IERC20` interface, which does not include any of the custom functions you mentioned. Instead of `IERC20`, you should use the `SolarGreen` contract interface.

Change the following code:

```
contract TokenSale{
    IERC20 public token;
```

To:

```
contract TokenSale{
    SolarGreen public token;
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, you are right